# jQuery UI Datepicker Month & Year Menus Only Work Once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using [jQuery UI's month and year menus](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year). Here's what's happening and where I'm running into an issue:

- Click the date field
- Change the month dropdown to Jan
- Change the year dropdown to 2003
- Click the calendar day 1
- The date field is correctly populated with 01/01/2003

Here's where I run into the issue:

- Click the date field (again)
- Change the month (or year) dropdown
- The date does not change
- Click off of the datepicker to hide it
- The date still does not change

Is there a way to use the month or year dropdowns after a date has been entered?

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanburnett/8N9Xq/

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  });
```

Comment: it's working fiddle what's the problem

Comment: If you select a date, then try to change the month or year, it won't work.

Comment: Work as expected on the documentation : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, the month-year change doesn't refresh the datepicker; you can set the new selected date (from dropdowns too) using the [`onChangeMonthYear`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear) option:

> Called when the datepicker moves to a new month and/or year. The
>   function receives the selected year, month (1-12), and the datepicker
>   instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Code:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, day) {
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month - 1, day.selectedDay));
    }
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xdhy/

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery-ui datepicker will change only if you clicked on **specific day**.

That just how they designed it.

if you want to use only months and years, better write a javascript of your own(its quicker, believe me...)